# How to deserialize a json field with varying type in kotlinx serialization?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

Consider the following json structure representing a basic check-in information

```
{
  "id": "53481198005",
  "date": "1995-01-01 00:00:00",
  "latitude": "50.765391",
  "longitude": "60.765391"
}
```

When API doesn't have latitude and longitude information, it sends them in int type with value 0 like this:

```
{
  "id": "53481198005",
  "date": "1995-01-01 00:00:00",
  "latitude": 0,
  "longitude": 0
}
```

And of course, when I try to deserialize it with the following class, it throws an exception.

```
@Serializable
data class CheckInRecord(
    val id: String,
    val date: String,
    val latitude: String?,
    val longitude: String?
)
```

Exception:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 457: Expected quotation mark '"', but had '0' instead
```

I want to deserialize them only if they are string. If they are int, I want to make them null. I already considered implementing a custom deserializer like in [kotlinx-deserialization documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#maintaining-custom-json-attributes). For example, checking field type by doing the following is possible by reaching JsonDecoder

```
val jsonInput = decoder as? JsonDecoder ?: error("error")
val json = jsonInput.decodeJsonElement().jsonObject
val isLongitudeString = json["longitude"]?.jsonPrimitive?.isString
```

but I want to implement a common deserializer for this kind of fields without repeating deserializer code. Above code, "longitude" is a hardcoded value making me implement multiple deserializers.

How can achieve this or something similar?

Comment: Perhaps enabling [lenient parsing](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#lenient-parsing) would work for you?